How to compute feature_importances_ on XGBoost considering only iterations up to best_iteration?
I trained an XGBRegressor model with early stopping. As far as I understood, model.feature_importances_ computes feature importances looking at ALL history (i.e. considering also the "patience" iterations quantified by early_stopping_rounds). Nonetheless, I need the feature importances computed on the model only up to the best_iteration.
Here is an exemplificative code:
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Prepare data
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, noise=0.1)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train the model with early stopping
xgb_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, early_stopping_rounds=100, eval_metric="rmse")
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_val, y_val)], verbose=False)

xgb_model.feature_importances_

But this gives me feature importances considering the full model, not just up to the best_iteration:
best_iteration = xgb_model.best_iteration

I can not re-train a new XGBRegressor with n_estimators=best_iteration because it would almost double running time (this snippet is part of a much larger code).
Is there a way to achieve this without re-training?
Note that, unfortunately, .feature_importances_ does not have an iteration_range option.

You can use the booster object using xgb_model.get_booster(). Then use the get_score() method with the best iteration to get the feature importances for the best model. Finally, Convert the feature scores into a format similar to feature_importances_.
Here is a sample code you can use:
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Prepare data
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, noise=0.1)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train the model with early stopping
xgb_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, early_stopping_rounds=100, eval_metric="rmse")
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_val, y_val)], verbose=False)

# Get the best iteration
best_iteration = xgb_model.best_iteration

# Access the booster and retrieve feature importances up to best_iteration
booster = xgb_model.get_booster()
importance_dict = booster.get_score(importance_type='weight', iteration=best_iteration)

# Convert the importance dict into a list of feature importances
importances = [importance_dict.get(f'f{i}', 0) for i in range(X.shape[1])]

# Print the importances
print(importances)


This is the kind of answer ChatGPT used to give me but it does not work with xgboost 2.0.0. I get the error TypeError: get_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iteration'. As I was saying, .feature_importances_ does not have an iteration_range option (nor an iteration option or anything similar). Same for . get_score().

This can be salvaged because the native boosters are sliceable. best_booster = booster[:best_iteration], then call get_score on that. Note that feature_importances_ uses gain (not weight) and is normalized when comparing.

@BenReiniger thanks a lot, it perfectly worked this way!
